# Link sharing with json callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i'm creating a link sharing that returns meta tags from url

So, i created a page that do it call **getmeta.php** and put all info into an array and finally encode with json

```
$url = $_GET['link'];

if(!empty($url)) {

function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
        $thumb = $meta->getAttribute('content');        
}

$page = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '$4', $url ); 

$arr = array('title' => $title, 'thumb' => $thumb, 'page' => $page, 'url' => $url);

echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

i do the callback in ajax with $.get method like this

```
function getThumb(url) {
    $.get( 'getmeta.php', { link : encodeURI(url) } , function( data ) {

                var title   = data[0].title;
                var page    = data[0].page;
                var thumb   = data[0].thumb;

                thumb_image.css({"background-image":"url("+thumb+")"});
                thumb_title.html('<span>' + title + '</span><span><i class="fa fa-link"></i>'+page+'</span>');

            }, "json" );
}
```

Now, the code seems corret but it returns empty call each times. I just can not figure out where i'm wrong. Any ideas ?

Comment: can you add `console.log(data )` in the callback to see whether it is getting called. Also check the browser network tab to see what is returned by the ajax request

Comment: Also try going directly to getmeta.php?link=foo in your browser to see if the problem is with the PHP or the JavaScript.

Comment: The assoc array in PHP will be translated into a json object, not an array object in JS. Your three variables in JS should therefore not contain `[0]`. I verified this using [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/), but u can verify this your self by doing as @ArunPJohny said. `echo json_encode(array('title' => "title", 'thumb' => "thumb", 'page' => "page", 'url' => "url"));` => `{"title":"title","thumb":"thumb","page":"page","url":"url"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('title' => "title", 'thumb' => "thumb", 'page' => "page", 'url' => "url");
echo json_encode($arr);

OUTPUT: {"title":"title","thumb":"thumb","page":"page","url":"url"}
```

Hence `data[0]` is undefined, and you are probably seeing errors in the console. If this is truly the source of your problem it is easily fixed by removing `[0]` for you three variabels in JS.

As @ArunPJohny mentions in his comment, you should really start using `console.log` to help you debug such problems.

Another problem your code may suffer from is that in your `$.get` callback function `data` is in fact a string. This needs to be parsed into JSON at some point, or you should simply use `$.getJSON` instead.